# Update (or Replace) item(s) in immutable collection in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, immutability, scala-collections

What is best practice to update (or replace) a item in Seq ?

```
case class Minion(id: Int, name: String, motivation: Int)
val minions: Seq[Minion] = Seq(
  Minion(1, "Bob", 50),
  Minion(2, "Kevin", 50),
  Minion(3, "Stuart", 50))
```

I'd like to acquire new Collection

```
Seq(
  Minion(1, "Bob", 50),
  Minion(2, "Kevin", 50),
  Minion(3, "Stuart", 100))
```

What's best way ?

Answer (score 6):

Use `updated`:

```
// first argument is index (zero-based) - so using 2 to replace 3rd item:
scala> minions.updated(2, Minion(3, "Stuart", 100))
res0: Seq[Minion] = List(Minion(1,Bob,50), Minion(2,Kevin,50), Minion(3,Stuart,100))
```

Or, without repeating the unchanged attributes of the new `Minion`:

```
scala> minions.updated(2, minions(2).copy(motivation = 100))
res1: Seq[Minion] = List(Minion(1,Bob,50), Minion(2,Kevin,50), Minion(3,Stuart,100))
```

Answer (score 2):

Map also works, and might be a little bit easier to read than `updated`:

```
minions.map {
  case Minion(2, name, n) => Minion(2, name, 100)
  case m => m
}
```

One benefit of this over `updated` besides readability is that you can modify several elements in one go.